# Why is this Hibernate servlet throwing an IllegalAccessError exception?

Tags: hibernate, netbeans

I tried to create a very small web app in NetBeans using Hibernate. I placed `hibernate3.jar` , `log4J-1.2.14.jar`, `sl4j.api.jar`, `sl4j-log4ja2-1.5.6.jar`, `dom4j-1.6.1.jar`, `jta.jar`, and `ehcache.jar` under the `Libraries` folder. I also placed `hibernate.cfg.xml` under the `default` package of the `source` folder and default `log4j.properties` file and `Book.hbm.xml` under another package of the `Source` folder. I don't know whether it is right or wrong. I wrote `Hibernate Manager` class for `sessionfactory` and controller servlet as follows. But if I run this servlet I get an exception.

Controller servlet:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import Syron.HibernateManager;
import Syron.BookInfo;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.util.List;

public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        HibernateManager manager = new HibernateManager(BookInfo.class);
        List categories = manager.findAll();
        request.setAttribute("categories", categories);
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        try
        {
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher("/welcomeJSF.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
        catch(Exception es)  {

        }
    } 

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } 

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse   response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

     public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }

}
```

Manager:

```
import java.util.*;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.util.*;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

//import org.slf4j.impl.*;

public class HibernateManager {
    private Class _cl;

    public  HibernateManager(Class cl)
    {
        _cl = cl;
    }

    public List findAll() throws HibernateException
    {
        List rv = new ArrayList();

        SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        try
        {
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config = config.configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml");
            sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (HibernateException ex)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception building SessionFactory: " +ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }

        rv = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(BookInfo.class).list();
        return rv;
    }

    public BookInfo findById(int id) throws HibernateException
    {
        Session session = SessionProvider.currentSession();
        BookInfo rv = (BookInfo) session.get(_cl, new Integer(id));
        return rv;
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.SINGLETON from class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.<clinit>(LoggerFactory.java:60)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:152)
    Syron.HibernateManager.findAll(HibernateManager.java:34)
    ControllerServlet.processRequest(ControllerServlet.java:40)
    ControllerServlet.doGet(ControllerServlet.java:62)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

I tried various things but couldn't fix this. Where did I go wrong? I also placed the `commons-logging.jar` file instead of `sl4j.jar` but then I get `No class definition found` exceptions for `org.sl4j.impl.?`. So I searched and replaced `sl4j-log4ja2-1.5.6.jar` and tried again as above. How can I use Hibernate in NetBeans?

Comment: you sir remind me why i want to stay away from Hibernate :D Configuration hell :(

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious problem in your stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.SINGLETON from class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
```

The answer is in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467879/hibernate-3-4-with-slf4j-and-log4j).