# Javax.servlet.ServletException

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, slf4j

I've just come onboard with a new team and I am trying to run their project within eclipse using GWT. I know the code is fine, but I keep getting a similar error.

javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportExporterService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/adminportal-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'reportService' while setting bean property 'reportService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportService' defined in class path resource [springconfig-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [springconfig-dao.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [springconfig-dao.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

```
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:437)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
 at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:616)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:461)
 at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
 at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:565)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:494)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1058)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:800)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:304)
```

Is there a plugin or compaibilty issue that you know of that could be causing this? Assuming the code itself is fine as I'm trying to run a stable release. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have some spring context creating problem. It would be useful if you put the full stacktrace.

Comment: Did you try cleaning and rebuilding your project?

Comment: can you search in all spring context xml files for the bean 'reportService' and make sure by checking in logs that the xml declaring that bean is loading. There may be other case (annotation driven or Auto-wiring too) so may be extend your search to .java files too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your project is missing slf4j jar(s).

Comment: Could this be an issue with Maven? I have m2clipse installed, how could i fix this?

Comment: I'm not using Maven, but the following links might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467879/hibernate-3-4-with-slf4j-and-log4j and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467879/hibernate-3-4-with-slf4j-and-log4j .

Answer (score 1):

It is a Spring bean configuration error: check that all the necessary Spring definitions are correct and that the Spring context xml files are in the right places.

Comment: Assuming that they are correct (i haven't modified code, I'm just trying to get my development environment running), what else do you know that could cause the error?

Comment: in terms of having a plugin not installed that should be and so on, thanks for any help

Comment: @Justin Heermann: Just keep looking down the stack trace. Somewhere near the bottom you will find the name/id of the bean that is causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse and have dependent projects to your web application, you need to add them to your workspace and have them open.