# Disabling Hibernate log messages in a Spring application

Tags: hibernate, spring, log4j, slf4j

I have configured my pom.xml to include slf4j and bindings to log4j and exclude commons-logging as explained [here](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring/) and disabled Hibernate's own logging as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467879/hibernate-3-4-with-slf4j-and-log4j).

I can suppress Spring's own messages, but Hibernate messages still come out despite my log4j.properties settings below.

```
log4j.debug=false
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, stdout
log4j.category.org.hibernate=ERROR, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
log4j.category.org.springframework = ERROR
log4j.category.org.hibernate = ERROR
```

[Here](http://dpaste.com/642634/) is my pom.xml file:

What could be the issue? I am seeing all the sql messages hibernate generates.

Comment: If you're using it, you might need to set `<property name="show_sql">false</property>` in your hibernate configuration file.

Comment: @XaviLópez Thanks, I had actually a similar one in my Spring application context, and setting it there solved the problem. I would mark your deleted answer as the answer. I find it still a bit strange that disabling in log4j's properties is not enough to suppress Hibernate's log messages, but this is Java EE, I shouldn't keep my hopes that high, should I?

Comment: I've undeleted the answer. I'd advice to post your own answer with the particular problem you had, and how you solved it. You can upvote mine if it helped you, of course :)  From the Hibernate Reference, using `show_sql=true` is equivalent to using `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG`. Maybe it was overwriting the trace level for the `SQL` subpackage. I don't have the means to test this now, but maybe someone else can shed some light on this :]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using it, you might need to set `<property name="show_sql">false</property>` in your hibernate configuration file.

Comment: For me this worked: <property name="show_sql" value="false"></property>

Answer (score 15):

If anyone looks up this question while browsing for answers:

IF you are using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, set `spring.jpa.show_sql = false` in your `application.properties` file.

Answer (score 11):

Complementing Jørgen Skår Fischer's answer, in my specific case I had to add both settings in the application.properties file.

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
```

and

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
```

Comment: The second line helped me get rid of the hibernate messages (I had the first line already set, but was still receiving the hibernate log messages).

Answer (score 4):

For those users who tried everything proposed and still saw the sql logs:

If you annotated your test with `@DataJpaTest`, set the (not so obvious) `showSql`-field inside to `false`.

```java
@DataJpaTest(showSql = false)
```

Comment: Wow! This was killing me. Thanks for the correct fix (in my case anyway!)

Answer (score 2):

And if you still can't disable show_sql try something like this

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=INFO
```